# KeyError when trying to read and change dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Context - I have a dataset of NFL games and currently each game is expressed as 2 rows, one for each team. I am writing code to show both teams on each row to eventually compress the dataframe to 1 row/game.

```
n2r['Home'] = 0
n2r['Away'] = 0

for i in np.arange(0,n2r.shape[0],2):
    if n2r.at[i,'VH'] == 'H':
        n2r.at[i,'Home'] = n2r['Team'][i]
        n2r.at[i+1,'Home'] = n2r['Team'][i]
        n2r.at[i,'Away'] = n2r['Team'][i+1]
        n2r.at[i+1,'Away'] = n2r['Team'][i+1]
    if n2r.at[i,'VH'] == 'V':
        n2r.at[i,'Away'] = n2r['Team'][i]
        n2r.at[i+1,'Away'] = n2r['Team'][i]
        n2r.at[i,'Home'] = n2r['Team'][i+1]
        n2r.at[i+1,'Home'] = n2r['Team'][i+1]
```

I also tried this same code using dataframe['column']['row'] rather than the dataframe.at method, but I run into the same problem.

My code works but stops for some reason after around 210 entries. You can see where it stops on the right side.
See pic below-

[code result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFDzD.png)

I get the error message below -

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diS5U.jpg)

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a sample (as text) of your dataset and the expected output ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your error as text and not as an image.

Comment: As stated, you're using i as the index value and it's range is from 0 to the len of the dataframe, when you actually want it to use the index. So in this case, you'd want to use either `iterrows()` or `itertuples()`

Comment: If you provide a sample of the dataset, and explain what you want the output to look like, there is likely a more efficient way to do this rather than iterating row by row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looking at the picture you've provided it seems that your dataframe `n2r` has some holes in the index.

[image]

It might be the case that you're performing the `for/loop`, based on the assumption that your dataframe's rows are indexed monotonically from 0 to `n2r.shape[0]`, when in fact that's not the case. One possible fix might be to reset the index before entering the `for/loop`:

```py
n2r = n2r.reset_index(drop=True)  # <-- Possible fix.

for i in np.arange(0, n2r.shape[0], 2):

    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "H":
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "V":
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
```

**For example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# -- Generate Dummy Dataframe to reproduce the issue ---------------------------------------
vh_values = ["H", "V"]
n2r = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "VH": map(vh_values.__getitem__, np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)),
        "Team": np.random.randint(0, 10, 50),
    }
)
n2r["Home"] = 0
n2r["Away"] = 0


# -- Poking a hole intentionally at the index values ----------------------------------------
l = n2r.index.to_list()
l[4] = len(l) + 2
n2r.index = l

for i in np.arange(0, n2r.shape[0], 2):

    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "H":
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "V":
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]

# Error Message:
"""
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3800, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3799 try:
-> 3800     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3801 except KeyError as err:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2263, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 4

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [30], in <cell line: 22>()
     20 n2r.index = l
     22 for i in np.arange(0, n2r.shape[0], 2):
---> 24     if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "H":
     25         n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
     26         n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:2427, in _AtIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   2424         raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!")
   2425     return self.obj.loc[key]
-> 2427 return super().__getitem__(key)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:2378, in _ScalarAccessIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   2375         raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!")
   2377 key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2378 return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3922, in DataFrame._get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   3916 engine = self.index._engine
   3918 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
   3919     # CategoricalIndex: Trying to use the engine fastpath may give incorrect
   3920     #  results if our categories are integers that dont match our codes
   3921     # IntervalIndex: IntervalTree has no get_loc
-> 3922     row = self.index.get_loc(index)
   3923     return series._values[row]
   3925 # For MultiIndex going through engine effectively restricts us to
   3926 #  same-length tuples; see test_get_set_value_no_partial_indexing

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3800     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3801 except KeyError as err:
-> 3802     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3803 except TypeError:
   3804     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3805     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3806     #  the TypeError.
   3807     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 4
"""
```

**With reset index:**

```py
# -- Generate Dummy Dataframe to reproduce the issue ---------------------------------------
vh_values = ["H", "V"]
n2r = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "VH": map(vh_values.__getitem__, np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)),
        "Team": np.random.randint(0, 10, 50),
    }
)
n2r["Home"] = 0
n2r["Away"] = 0


# -- Poking a hole intentionally at the index values ----------------------------------------
l = n2r.index.to_list()
l[4] = len(l) + 2
n2r.index = l

# -- Potential Fix --------------------------------------------------------------------------
n2r = n2r.reset_index(drop=True)


for i in np.arange(0, n2r.shape[0], 2):

    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "H":
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
    if n2r.at[i, "VH"] == "V":
        n2r.at[i, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Away"] = n2r["Team"][i]
        n2r.at[i, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]
        n2r.at[i + 1, "Home"] = n2r["Team"][i + 1]

n2r
# Prints:
#    VH  Team  Home  Away
# 0   V     7     0     7
# 1   V     0     0     7
# 2   H     9     9     7
# 3   V     7     9     7
# 4   H     7     7     0
# 5   V     0     7     0
# 6   H     5     5     4
# 7   V     4     5     4
# 8   H     8     8     5
# 9   H     5     8     5
# 10  H     3     3     4
# 11  H     4     3     4
# 12  V     6     0     6
# 13  V     0     0     6
# 14  V     0     9     0
# 15  V     9     9     0
# 16  V     6     0     6
# 17  H     0     0     6
# 18  V     2     9     2
# 19  V     9     9     2
# 20  H     5     5     8
# 21  H     8     5     8
# 22  H     0     0     5
# 23  H     5     0     5
# 24  V     6     4     6
# 25  V     4     4     6
# 26  V     8     8     8
# 27  H     8     8     8
# 28  H     9     9     8
# 29  V     8     9     8
# 30  H     4     4     3
# 31  V     3     4     3
# 32  H     7     7     1
# 33  V     1     7     1
# 34  H     9     9     1
# 35  V     1     9     1
# 36  V     2     4     2
# 37  H     4     4     2
# 38  H     1     1     4
# 39  H     4     1     4
# 40  H     3     3     7
# 41  V     7     3     7
# 42  H     0     0     4
# 43  V     4     0     4
# 44  V     7     7     7
# 45  V     7     7     7
# 46  H     6     6     6
# 47  H     6     6     6
# 48  V     3     3     3
# 49  V     3     3     3
```